# why does my tr ng-repeat dissapear when clicking on pagination links

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-resource

Using angular-bootstrap server-side pagination and $resource/$http. I am running a search and returning multiple records. I then use ng-repeat on a tr element to populate the table. This is all fine. the issue arises when i click on any pagination button. Before anything happens, (ie. resource calls or dom manipulation) the tr I am using the ng-repeat on is removed from the DOM. Any ideas why and how to avoid this in the future?

My html, the TR element:

```
<tr class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="agent in agentDataModel">
```

Pagination HTML

```
<div class="text-center">
        <pagination                 
            data-ng-model="agentDataModel"
            data-page="agentDataModel.currentPage"
            data-total-items="agentDataModel.totalItems"
            data-items-per-page="25"
            data-max-size="5" 
            data-ng-change="setPage(2)"
            >                    
        </pagination>
    </div>
```

My controller - submit search function

```
$scope.submitSearch = function(newSearchVal, pageNo) {
        $rootScope.moduleLoading = true;

        agentService.get(newSearchVal)
            .$promise.then(
            function success(r) {
                $rootScope.moduleLoading = false;

                if(typeof r.total_items !== 'undefined') { 
                    if(r.total_items > 0 ) {
                        // May be one or multiple results (variable results)

                        // fetch agents and map the data to $scope var
                        $scope.$parent.agentDataModel               = r._embedded.agents;
                        // set pagination options
                        $scope.$parent.agentDataModel.itemsPerPage  = r.page_size;
                        $scope.$parent.agentDataModel.page_count    = r.page_count;
                        $scope.$parent.agentDataModel.totalItems    = r.total_items;
                        $scope.$parent.agentDataModel.currentPage   = 1;                            
                        $scope.$parent.agentDataModel.links         = r._links;
                        $scope.$parent.agentDataModel.next          = r._links.next.href;
                        $scope.$parent.agentDataModel.page          = r.page;

                        // set flags
                        $scope.$parent.singleResult                 = false;
                        $scope.$parent.showResult                   = true;

                        // debug
                        if($rootScope.env === 'dev') {dev.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.$parent.currentPage);}
                    } else {
                        // HMMM no results? Set flags
                        $scope.$parent.singleResult = false;
                        $scope.$parent.showResult   = false;
                        $scope.$parent.alert.info   = true;
                        showInfoAlert('We found 0 agents with that search.','n');                        
                    }
                } else {
                   // Absolutly one result ready for the form view
                   // set flags
                    $scope.$parent.showResult       = true;
                    $scope.$parent.singleResult     = true;
                    $scope.$parent.isHidden         = false;
                    // set single agent data
                    $scope.$parent.agentDataModel   = r;
                }                   
            }, 
            function error(msg) {
                $rootScope.moduleLoading = false;
                dev.log('error');
                dev.log(msg);
                var myError             = msg;
                var theQuery            = myError.config.params.query;
                var myErrorURL          = myError.config.url;
                var myErrorType         = myError.data.type;
                var myErrorTitle        = myError.data.title;
                var myErrorStatus       = myError.status;
                var myErrorStatusText   = myError.statusText;
                var myErrorDetail       = myError.statusText;
                var myErrorMsg          = "FATAL ERROR - The search with query ?query="+ theQuery +"! The URL: " + myErrorURL + 
                            " responded with a status of " + myErrorStatus +": "+ myErrorStatusText + 
                            ". DETAILS: " + myErrorDetail+". "+ 
                            "Please click this link to send an error report <a href='mailto:xxxxx@xxxxxx.com?subject=Search Error&body="+myErrorURL+"'>" + myErrorURL + 
                            "</a>.";
                showErrorAlert(myErrorMsg);                    
            }
        );  
    };
```

Of course any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You iterate `agentDataModel` like an array yet it also has `currentPage` and `totalItems` properties? According to the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination), the `ng-model` of the `<pagination>` directive should be the current page number. There's also no `page` / `data-page` attribute

Comment: You can try disabling the pagination while the data is loading, by using the attribute data-ng-disabled. I see you have rootScope.moduleLoading variable, you can set that to a $scope variable and use it in data-ng-disabled.

Comment: @phil thank you, that did lend to the solution. The page / data-page attr is there. but I needed to add the currentPage key to the model I was using. so the change was:     `data-ng-model="agentDataModel.currentPage"`  the agentDataModel is an array of arrays, so yes the currentPage and totalItems values are in there

Comment: @Phil you should post your comment as an answer and i will choose that as best answer.